# Php print format or print php value to html scope

Tags: php, html, sql

hello i am new in php and im trying to print some values from my sql table to an article in html i use article because this is the structure i need . as you will see bellow i basically want to take the path and the username from my sql table and print them to my article any suggestions?

```
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


        <title>Corporate 1</title>


        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">


    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> 
                        Logo
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Navbar links -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Products</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
                                <li><a href="#">Engage</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Pontificate</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Synergize</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Search -->
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>

        <div class="jumbotron feature">
            <div class="container">
                <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-equalizer"></span><font color="#F0FFFF" style="Impact">Welcome to Aegean Community</font></h1>
                <p><font color="#E9967A">Community for hope</font></p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="LogIn.php">Engage Now</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="container">

            <!-- Heading -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Superior Collaboration
                        <small>Visualize Quality</small>
                    </h1>
                    <p>Proactively envisioned multimedia based expertise and cross-media growth strategies. Seamlessly visualize quality intellectual capital without superior collaboration and idea-sharing. Holistically pontificate installed base portals after maintainable products.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->

            <!-- Feature Row -->
            <div class="row">
             <!-- Feature Row -->


                <?php
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "root";
                $password = "";
                $dbname = "some";

                // Create connection
                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                // Check connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM information order by Ranking desc LIMIT 3 ";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        ?>

                <article class="col-md-4 article-intro">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src=" <?php echo $row['imgagePath'] ?>" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <h3>
                        <a href="#"> <?php echo $row['username'] ?></a>
                    </h3>

                </article>
               <?php
                }
                ?>




            </div>


        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `echo` before the variable that you want to print to HTML.

```
src=" <?php $row['imgagePath'] ?>"
```

should become

```
src=" <?php echo $row['imgagePath']; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use echo $row['var'] to tell PHP to insert that value on the page as a string.

Just change:

```
<?php $row['imgagePath'] ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $row['imgagePath']; ?>
```

and

```
<?php $row['username'] ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $row['username']; ?>
```

That should be about all you need to do

Comment: yea i have tried this too id gives me error in the last line that sais Syntax error unexpacted end of file so i thowght mayby my code was false let me post the hole index\

Comment: make sure you have the semi-colon after each echo line.  The guy below me forgot those too as it's easy to do.  Are you sure you've tried it exactly like posted above?  If so, go ahead and add your whole index file

Answer (score 0):

The major error here is not using an outputting the collected data per $row using `echo` and you're also missing the semicolon `;`.

So changing `<?php $row['username'] ?>` to `<?php echo $row['username'] ?>` and `<?php $row['imgagePath'] ?>` to `<?php echo $row['imgagePath']; ?>` should do the trick, I believe that's major error you're encountering.

Also instead of using `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {` you're better off using while `($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):` then you can simply replace the closing bracket `}` with `endwhile;`. The same goes for `if (expr):` and `endif;`.

Altogether it should look something like this:

```
 <!-- Feature Row -->
            <div class="row">

                <?php
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "root";
                $password = "";
                $dbname = "some";

                // Create connection
                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                // Check connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM information order by Ranking desc LIMIT 3 ";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0):
                    // output data of each row
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):
                        ?>
                </article>
                <article class="col-md-4 article-intro">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src=" <?php echo $row['imgagePath']; ?>" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <h3>
                        <a href="#"> <?php echo $row['username']; ?></a>
                    </h3>

                </article>
               <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
            ...
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Sometimes you overshoot it and forget the smallest things; been there done that. @giorgosfiotakis